# Clean architecture for 2 fragments that are similar in function with MVVM?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, architecture, single-responsibility-principle

I'm working on an android app in Kotlin that has user profiles, and I'm trying my best to code as clean as possible, using MVVM. While working on the part responsible for updating user's profile, I noticed that the model (POJO), viewmodel and the fragment itself are 90% similar with the ones responsible for registering the user. My question is what design should I choose and why:

1. make the 2 actions separate, respecting the single responsibility principle, but have a lot of duplicate code
2. merge them into one single action (one viewmodel, model and fragment), with some extra if's here and there

Or is there another way? Maybe with interfaces? Inheritances? How should one implement this?

Answer (score 0):

MVVM has three strong part for clean way coding. VIEW - MODEL - ViewModel

1. Your fragment will be **VIEW** for showing profiles and taking action from user
2. **ViewModel** will be for calculating or manipulating profiles data
3. **Model/Repo** for generating/getting profiles data from or to server/storage

**Fragments** <-> **ViewModel** <-> **Repo/Model**

Comment: I understand that, but my question is if I should value the single responsibility principle more than not having messy & duplicate code

Comment: In here, though few extra code but it will benefit you for long run. You have any future change in data population then this will sure affect the updating to fragment reference cause single principle highly and directly involve in same code base. If you need to change few logics the which also affect both fragment and profiles data cause it resides in same place. To manage your codes layer independent, you must to ignore to have few extra code for MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Use inheritance to keep the common code in a basefragmet / viewmodel . So you have :

UserProfileUpdateFragment -> UserProfileFragment
UserProfileRegisterFragment -> UserProfileFragment

or

UserProfileUpdateVM -> UserProfileVM
UserProfileRegisterVM -> UserProfileVM